# Selenium Python Chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

While running the script via chrome error is coming but same code is running OM in Firefox.

Error:
D:\SeleniumPOC>python CC2.py
[2564:4732:1028/082336:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(102)] Can't retrieve a va
lid WinSAT assessment.
[2564:4732:1028/082344:ERROR:textfield.h(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class CC2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://google.com"
        time.sleep(5)
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
```

I have placed my chrome driver exe in c/python27/Scripts folder

Comment: If you are talking about errors seen in ChromeDriver's console window, then yes, it's expected. What's the problem?

Comment: What why these errors are coming .. are they going to hamper my test case in any way?

Comment: The errors will not affect your test case in any way.